# Displaying ﷺ in javafx

Tags: javafx, non-unicode

How could I display the character ﷺ in `javafx`
I have tried the following, but it is showing weird characters instead.

```
ar_full_moon_hadith = " عَنْ جَرِيرِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ عَنْ النَّبِيِّ ﷺ قَالَ : صِيَامُ ثَلاثَةِ أَيَّامٍ مِنْ كُلِّ شَهْرٍ صِيَامُ الدَّهْرِ وَأَيَّامُ الْبِيضِ صَبِيحَةَ ثَلاثَ عَشْرَةَ وَأَرْبَعَ عَشْرَةَ وَخَمْسَ عَشْرَةَ ";
```

code below:

```
ar_moon_hadith_Label_L1.setVisible(true);
ar_moon_hadith_Label_L1.setText(ar_full_moon_hadith);
ar_moon_hadith_Label_L1.setId("ar_moon-notification-text1");
```

using the css below

```
#ar_moon-notification-text1{

        -fx-font-size: 22px;
        -fx-font-family: 'Lateef';
        -fx-text-alignment: right;
        -fx-text-fill:white;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of how it looks and code for what exactly you have tried?

Comment: code now s showing, however for the screen shit it is hard to do, however it is showing 2 weird characters instead

Comment: apparently there is a unicode for it: Unicode number U+FDFA